# JSoup search by attribute and class

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

You can do:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

to find all "a" elements with an href attribute.

And you can do:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("title")
```

to get all elements with a class that is called "title"

But how can I do both? (I.e search for an "a" element with an "href" tag that also has the class "title").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply have

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href].title");
```

This will select all `<a>` having an `href` attribute with a `title` class. The class is passed [by prepending it with a dot](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

> #### Selector combinations
>
> - Any combination, e.g. `a[href].highlight`

Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(""
            + "<div>"
            + "  <a href='link1' class='title another'>Link 1</a>"
            + "  <a href='link2' class='another'>Link 2</a>"
            + "  <a href='link3'>Link 3</a>"
            + "</div>");

    Elements links = doc.select("a[href].title");
    System.out.println(links); // prints "<a href="link1" class="title another">Link 1</a>"
}
```